# IBM Platform LSF Exit code=139

Tags: sas, batch-processing, lsf

I've faced with error while executing SAS batch command.
Batch command executes by IBM Platform LSF.
`bhist` command shows following:

[image]

The job exited with exit code 139. According to LSF admin guide jobs terminated with a system signal are returned by LSF as exit codes greater than 128. So the signal code =139-128 -> 11 - SIGSEGV.

What does this code mean? How can I determine the root cause of problem? The job worked without errors last day.

Comment: Can you reproduce the segfault when running the program outside of LSF?

Answer (score 2):

Igor,

The issue is caused by your OS or hardware. I would say if you run the job again, it will most likely run fine.

SIGSEGV is a memory segmentation error that could be caused in many different ways, not necessarally by your SAS job, but usually it is a one off error.

The following are some typical causes of a segmentation fault:

- Dereferencing null pointers – this is special-cased by memory management hardware
- Attempting to access a nonexistent memory address (outside process's address space)
- Attempting to access memory the program does not have rights to (such as kernel structures in process context)
- Attempting to write read-only memory (such as code segment)

These in turn are often caused by programming errors that result in invalid memory access:

- Dereferencing or assigning to an uninitialized pointer (wild pointer, which points to a random memory address)
- Dereferencing or assigning to a freed pointer (dangling pointer, which points to memory that has been freed/deallocated/deleted)
- A buffer overflow
- A stack overflow
- Attempting to execute a program that does not compile correctly. 
  (source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault)

If you want to trace the error, I need to know your platform. For example, this error would be captured in Windows Administrative Tools where you can find more information. Other platforms would capture this sort of error in different ways.

I hope it helps.

Regards,
Vasilij

Comment: Vasilij, thanks for your reply. But I need to know the reason: "error that could be caused in many different ways" - what are theese ways? How can I determine it?

Comment: @IgorKhalin fair enought. I have updated my answer with possible causes. You will need to look into your OS logs to find more information.